# Please clarify SMTP encryption protocol and ports (between servers only)

Tags: email, ssl, encryption, smtp, starttls

Could someone please clarify the typical ways a mail SERVER connects to another in order to deliver an encrypted email?

I understand that the STARTTLS command is intended to upgrade the tcp connection to TLS, but am I really expected (as a server) to do that on remote port 25?

I built my own SMTP server (no encryption, in perl) and it hosts all my emails, but I never saw in the logs any remote server trying to send STARTTLS. So is my server supposed to also run on another port? Why no one ever tried STARTTLS?

And lastly, if I want people to see that lock icon in Gmail, when I connect to google MX servers to send an email all I have to do is start a TLS session with STARTTLS on that port 25? Do I need a certificate validated by an authority just like SSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... deliver an encrypted email?

First, there is a difference between transferring encrypted mails and the use of STARTTLS you ask about. Encrypting mails refers usually to end-to-end encryption using PGP or S/MIME, i.e. the sender encrypts and the recipient decrypts the mail. STARTTLS instead is not end-to-end but only hop-by-hop encryption: each hop (mail server) on the way has access to the plain mail and only the transport between the hops is encrypted.

> ... upgrade the tcp connection to TLS, but am I really expected (as a server) to do that on remote port 25?

You are expected to use port 25 since this is the only port which is defined for delivery in connection with an MX record. The relevant standard for STARTTLS is [RFC 3207](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt). It describes a SMTP extension where the receiving mail server can announce support for STARTTLS inside the response to EHLO and the client (i.e. another mail server or a mail user agent) can then upgrade the current connection using the STARTTLS command. In short the flow is like this:

```
< 220 server.example.com SMTP ready
> EHLO client.example.org
> 250-8BITMIME
> 250 STARTTLS
> STARTTLS
< 220 go ahead
... TLS handshake happens, initiated by client ...
> EHLO client.example.com
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
...
```

> ... but I never saw in the logs any remote server trying to send STARTTLS

If you don't announce support for STARTTLS in the response to EHLO the client will not try STARTTLS.

> ... see that lock icon in Gmail, when I connect to google MX servers to send an email all I have to do is start a TLS session with STARTTLS on that port 25? Do I need a certificate validated by an authority just like SSL?

A certificate is only needed in case you are the mail server receiving mails and thus work as TLS server if STARTTLS is used. In case of sending mails to gmail you are the client sending mails. In this case you might use a client certificate but you don't need to. And since you are working with Perl: the current versions of `Net::SMTP` (starting with version 3.x) have support for TLS already included as long as `IO::Socket::SSL` is installed. You just need to add a call to `starttls` as documented to send mails with TLS.

Answer (score 0):

> *I understand that the STARTTLS command is intended to upgrade the tcp connection to TLS, but am I really expected (as a server) to do that
>   on remote port 25?*

Yes. As defined by RFC 3207
For "real" SSL connections, ports 465 or 587 are used although 465 shouldn't be used anymore.
I don't understand about your clients since you're asking about server protocols.